# Reducing a scaling formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

$X$ can be between 4 and 10

For every number $X$ is below 10, reduce $Y$ by 5%

For example, if $X=7$, then $Y'=0.85Y$

```
(100 - (5 * (10 - X))) * Y / 100
```

Can I reduce that expression any further? I want to make it 'cleaner' when the next developer has to look at it.

Comment: You can reduce it algebraically, but if your question is about how readable it is in code then that's more of a programming (or at least programming style) question which would probably belong on a different SE site.

Comment: Cool, so how would you reduce it algebraically?

Comment: $(X+10)Y/20$...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the first step for reducing the expression above algebraically, using the [distributive law of multiplication](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/distributive-law.html):

$(100 - (5 \cdot (10 - X))) \cdot Y/100 = (100 - (50 - 5X)) \cdot Y/100$

Proceed further with the other [basic rules of Algebra](https://www.cuemath.com/algebra/basic-of-algebra/), and you should arrive at Gerry's answer.